# verify of ionic code structure

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

Can anybody please verify this code in pure ionic-2 format. 
    Since I am bit confuse to check properly. 
    If This is not good format then What it could be?

```
`<ion-content padding>
   <div class="main-contain"  col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3>
      <div class="header">
         <h2 text-center class="vision">Vision Logistica</h2>
         <hr col-6 class="hrow">
         <h3 text-center class="vision">Ciao, inserisci i tuoi dati 
            per<br/>accedere
         </h3>
         <hr col-6 class="hrow">
      </div>
      <h5 text-center>oppure</h5>
      <div class="form" col-11>
         <form [formGroup]="login" >
            <div class="username">
               <ion-item>
                  <ion-label stacked class="labels">Username</ion-label>
                  <ion-input class="inputs" type="text" 
[(ngModel)]="username" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
               </ion-item>
            </div>
            <div class="password">
               <ion-item>
                  <ion-label stacked class="labels">Password</ion-label>
                  <ion-input class="inputs" type="password" 
[(ngModel)]="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
               </ion-item>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</ion-content>`
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using visual studio than use command `Alt + shift + f` to format the html code

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-content padding>
    <div class="main-contain" col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3>
        <div class="header">
            <h2 text-center class="vision">Vision Logistica</h2>
            <hr col-6 class="hrow">
            <h3 text-center class="vision">Ciao, inserisci i tuoi dati
                per<br />accedere
            </h3>
            <hr col-6 class="hrow">
        </div>
        <h5 text-center>oppure</h5>
        <div class="form" col-11>
            <form [formGroup]="login">
                <div class="username">
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label stacked class="labels">Username</ion-label>
                        <ion-input class="inputs" type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" formControlName="username"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                </div>
                <div class="password">
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label stacked class="labels">Password</ion-label>
                        <ion-input class="inputs" type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>`
```

Perfect right dear.
Alt + shift + f in visual studio code
and if you don't use visual studio code
you can format online if your code doesn't leak information in third party page